# Using _e() on text inside video tags prints that text, instead of only showing when html5 <video> element is not supported

Tags: shortcode, translation, videos, html5

I'm creating a wordpress theme in which I'm creating a shortcode for a video. Part of the output of this shortcode is something like this:

```
   $result .= '<video class="fullWidth" width="auto" height="auto" loop muted preload>';
    $result .= '<source src="'.$mp4.'" type="video/mp4" />';
    $result .= '<source src="'.$webm.'" type="video/webm" />';
    $result .= '<source src="'.$ogv.'" type="video/ogv" />';
    $result .= _e('Video tag is not supported in your browser.', 'my-theme-framework');
   $result .= '</video>';
```

Now the video is working but the text 'Vide tag is ...' is getting echoed out, but when I remove the text from the function, it gets hidden. So I believe it is because of the _e() function and I do not know what to do. I need that to make the text translation ready, should I remove it?

I've searched around for this, but I'm getting no relevant results. Please tell me if you know what I should do here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) echoes the translated string, which will not work in variable assignment. You need to use [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2), which `return`s the translated string.